# Should I be worried if someone has my app keystore?

Tags: android

I had my game ported from iOS to Android and I know absolutely nothing about Android. The developer I hired used his keystore file for the app. Should I be worried? And is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Did you release the app yet?

Comment: @CommonsWare may know more about this. but your keystore is basically YOU. its your brand, your identity when it comes to signing the apk. by him using his key, the app belongs to him. if you have any in app purchased, potentially, you could loose those earnings....since the app is his because of his keystore.

Comment: Yes , As @DroiDev said, you should manage the release of your app.

Comment: I haven't released the app yet. So can I change the keystore to mine?

Answer (score 1):

so first is to understand your keystore
Your keystore is used to generate your APK with a password and upload to the Market.

Once you have uploaded to the market that keystore and password are locked for that app. If the developer has a copy of your keystore and password, they could create an identical bundle id application and sign it with same keystore and password and steal your spot on the market.

You would get an email of course, so you could catch that they did it.
Google would likely work with you on this to get it recovered and replaced.

However, you can simply opt-in for app signing on the market now to allow uploading of your current keystore to the app store. This allows you to recover if you ever lose your password or keystore info. This is a nice new feature, but won't stop you from having it stolen obviously.

Now, if the app has NOT been released to the market yet, simply create a new keystore and password and go from there.

If it is on the store, you can change the bundle id if you don't have a large user base yet, and delete the old app and create a new keystore and password for the same app with your new bundle id.

example
com.mysite.myapp
could become
com.mysite.mynewapp

now for future reference. Please do not allow engineers to have your production password. They can help you create a keystore and then you type the password. Then move the keystore either into the repo as part of the signing or to your CI build machine for generating builds.

The password should be secure, a common way to do this is in an environment variable on the build server so only the build server assembleRelease would work as the rest would not find the local environment variable value of MY_SIGNING_KEY.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok so I talked to my developer about it and this is what he said: “if you want to use your own keystore, you would need to create it and share it with us so that we can create a new app and go through the entire app store process afresh. But if you dont want to share it with us, you have to do that on your own. 
Since you didnt share your keystore, we decided to use ours for development. 
Let me know how you would like to proceed. ” so what should I do? I didn’t release the app publicly yet so is it simple to change the keystore?

Comment: Am I supposed to create my own keystore and give it to them and give them the key password or the keystore password?

Comment: Yes @Besere you will need to create your own if you do not want them to have a copy. Also if you give it to them with the password then you are no better off then if they made their own. They only need it if you are letting them release to the store for you. Which they should not be doing. It should either be done from a CI machine to generate builds (someone can setup for you if you don't know how) then they can just take the APK from there and distribute it. Otherwise, you need to get setup to build the APK yourself, which is very simple, just depends on your comfort level